# Emacs does not see new installation of Org-Mode

Tags: emacs

I had installed org-mode version 8.2.1 from emacs list-packages.
I downloaded the latest version 8.2.4 and placed it in .emacs.d and added the following to my .emacs,

`(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/org-8.2.4/lisp")`

Emacs still reports org-mode version to be 8.2.1

Comment: Did you close and restart EMACS after the change to .emacs?

Comment: Why not use list-packages to install or update to version **20131209**? The default installation directory when using list-packages is `~/.emacs.d/elpa`. Is your `user-emacs-directory` set to `~/.emacs.d/` -- `(setq user-emacs-directory "~/.emacs.d/")`?

Comment: This could happen when you require an org feature before you modify the `load-path`.
To check this, put `add-to-list` at the *top* of `~/.emacs` and `(require 'org)` straight after.

Comment: @abo-abo I have it at the top. Still the same result.

Comment: @lawlist yes the old installation is in the elpa directory. I wanted to install version 8.2.4 in place of 20131209.

Comment: `list-packages` now has the latest version available as of today (December 17, 2013) -- `Org-mode version 8.2.4 (8.2.4-8-gf1b933-elpa @ /Users/HOME/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20131216/)`

Comment: I'm not sure when the variable `package-load-list` was first introduced; however, a fairly recent version of Emacs Trunk contains a variable in `package.el` called `package-load-list`, which can be used to enable or disable packages -- see http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Package-Installation.html  The default value is `all`.

Comment: @lawlist. That was a stroke of luck; anyways, I now have the new version. :)

Comment: @abo-abo Thanks that was my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing old installation(s) of org-mode from the `load-path` first:

```
  (require 'cl)

  ;; Org-mode that was shipped with Emacs
  (setq load-path (remove-if (lambda (x) (string-match-p "org$" x)) load-path))
  ;; ELPA 
  (setq load-path (remove-if (lambda (x) (string-match-p "org-20" x)) load-path))

  (setq custom-org-path "~/.emacs.d/org-8.2.4/lisp")   
  (add-to-list 'load-path custom-org-path)
```

Also make sure to do it as early as possible in your `init.el` - especially if you use org-mode-based system for your emacs configuration files.

Comment: "Symbol's function definition is void: remove-if"

This is the response I got from emacs. Is remove-if function part of the emacs library?

Comment: Thanks for your continued help. This time there was no errors in loading .emacs, but the org-version is still 8.2.1

Comment: Can you try calling help for `org-version` using `C-h f org-version`? Then, on the help page, click on `org.el` and see what is the path to that file.

Comment: "~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20131021/org.el"

So it still finds the older version.

Comment: I see, if you don't want to uninstall it, try adding another `remove-if` line to your init.el, see my updated answer.

Comment: I have an update. I printed the load path, and the ".emacs.d/elpa/org-20131021" entry occurs before ".emacs.d/org-8.2.4/lisp". Does this affect anything?

Comment: Yes, emacs will use whatever is earlier in the load path, try adding the second `remove-if` line as I suggested.

Comment: So, if I have a special load path such as /my/path/the_borg, will this get recognized and removed from my load-path ?

Comment: Yes, `remove-if` will take care of everything for which `string-match-p` finds a match.

Comment: I used your approach via `C-h v load-path RET`, `C-s org RET`, and `(setq load-path (delete "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/org" load-path))`. Then added load paths as suggested. I also `C-h v load-history` when trying to watch for if I had loaded org while troubleshooting, since `M-x org-version` will load org. (But your solution would have circumvented all my problems, just took me some time to get everything lined up properly.)

Answer (score -1):

Add the following to your init.el file.

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
```

From the org compact guide [here](http://orgmode.org/elpa.html).